# finding approximate word in string

Tags: python, fuzzy-search

I would like to find a way to match approximate a word in a string so that the following example would return something greather than 90%.

```
magic_function("ASNIERES CO",'‘SARL ASN1ERES CO 92600 ASN1ERES SUR SEINE')
```

Comment: 1 out of 11 characters NOT correct : 1 vs capital i ... so 87% sounds about right

Comment: I know it sounds right, I was looking for another way of solving this problem :)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain what you're looking for. You could say "if the match is greater than 70%, return True" or something along those lines. It's unclear what you're asking for.